# How to save PDF file in JS (from ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, download, php-curl

I use PHP to get it, because I need to download a PDF file from another server. To download this file I need to be logged in and the client shouldn't have to log in there.

The problem is that the PDF file the user gets is just a white page.
On my server there is still content inside when i write it in a file (`file_put_contents("test.pdf",$content);`)

I tried to base64 encode it before I send it and recognized that the delivered data is still correct. So it fails at the decoding (`atob(data)`) or in the download function.
(I also tried utf8 encodings)

In the downloaded pdf file, many characters are exchanged with these boxes or question marks(��).

```php
$result = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents("test.pdf",$result); //test.pdf contains correct document
echo base64_encode($result);
```

```js
download(atob(data),"My.pdf") //data is answer of ajax request

function download(data, filename, type) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {
        type: type
    });
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
    else { // Others
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
            url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the implicit UTF8 encoding in the BLOB constructor.
More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761039/javascript-download-binary-data-without-base64).

Answer (score -1):

To display a pdf (or any other file type), you will have to set the content type and so on in response header for the browser to resolve it correctly and display. This is a small portion of a code I wrote for delivering pdf content to the user.

```
  $file = '/home/public_html/DriveMode/DRIVES/java.pdf'; //path to file
  $filename = 'filename.pdf';
  header('Content-type: application/pdf'); //setting content type in header
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes'); 
  readfile($file); // reads and writes the file to output buffer
```

Hope this helps you and do let me know in comments if something is confusing here.

Comment: This is not answering my question. Thats just a normal download of a pdf file.

Comment: I have no idea what is stored in `$result` but when you use `file_put_contents("test.pdf",$result);`, you are actually writing the contents of `$result` to the file `test.pdf` and you want to deliver the resulting `file`. So technically you should be echoing `test.pdf` and not `$result` and to do so, you need to set `content type as pdf` and so on in `response header` like I have done.

Comment: test.pdf is just a test as the name and the description says. Also I cant use this file when there are multiple users. `$result` is the whole test.pdf so i can use '$result' and as declared I dont want to display the pdf somewhere, just send it to js via xhr and save it, so i dont need this headers.