# Javascript download binary data without base64

Tags: javascript

I want to download some binary data but Chrome forces it to utf-8 which messes up the bytes. If I set `href` to a data URI and use base64 encoding it works, but I want to avoid that and use a BLOB instead.

Is there a way to stop Chrome from converting this binary data to utf-8?

```js
const data = "\x00\xff\xfe\xe2"
console.log(data)
const file = new Blob([data])

const a = document.getElementById("a")
const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
a.href = url;
a.download = "test.txt";
```

```html
<a id="a">Download</a>
```

In this example, you can see that my string contains the bytes

`00 ff fe e2`

and I convert that string to a blob. But when you download the file in Chrome and look at the bytes again you'll find

`20 c3 bf c3 be c3 a2`

instead. 
What I think is happening is that chrome takes each byte, reads it as utf-16 and converts it to utf-8. For example `fe` is `þ` when read as utf-16 but `c3 be` in utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are implicitly encoded as UTF-8 by the [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) constructor, so pass a typed array instead, such as [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array):

```js
const data = "\x00\xff\xfe\xe2"
console.log(data)
const file = new Blob([Uint8Array.from(data, c => c.charCodeAt(0))])

const a = document.getElementById("a")
const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
a.href = url;
a.download = "test.txt";
```

```html
<a id="a">Download</a>
```

Comment: MDN does mention that `DOMStrings are encoded as UTF-8` but I never thought that Blob would reencode the string, since Blobs are used for binary data. What also confused me a lot was that Blob replaces the UTF-16 BOM `FE FF` with the UTF-8 BOM `EF BB BF` and ignores existing UTF-8 BOMs. The MIME type also does not matter

Comment: @Wendelin blobs are not for the explicit purpose of binary data. Their purpose is to represent files in memory, and that includes plaintext files. The MIME type does not affect encoding, it only affects how other browser APIs choose to interpret the file data when there are multiple options available (e.g. differentiating `image/gif` and `image/png` when using a [Blob URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) as the `src` of an `<img>`)